# Eclipse not letting me edit .jsp file - read only

Tags: eclipse, perforce

I am working with `Perforce` and `Eclipse`. I just created a new .jsp file in my workspace but when I try to edit it, it gives me the following error:

[image: error message]

Whether I click `Get Latest` or `Don't Get Latest` I am unable to edit the file. What are the steps I can take to change this file from read-only to editable?

Comment: Make sure that you are not editing some generated output files instead of your source files.

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: Have you verified via P4 or P4V that the check out function completed successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click the file in project explorer go to `properties` and uncheck `read-only`. This will let you start editing your file again.

Comment: This is not recommended because it means that Perforce will not notice that the file has been modified unless you reconcile or try to sync over it.

Comment: Which proves my point that you should check out the file in the first place.

Comment: If you didn't pay attention to the question or answer, checking it out does NOT enable it to be edited.